# Local, small, single user CRM software

Tags: windows-7, crm

I have managed my offers, customers and invoices with Microsoft Access for years. Recently I upgraded from my very old version to Office 2013 Home and Business, which does not include Microsoft Access any more.

Since I need MS Access only for this one task, I think it should be possible to replace it. The application must

- Store customers with

  - customer ID
  - address
  - email address
- Store offers with

  - offer ID
  - customer ID (foreign key)
  - date
  - valid until date
- Store invoices with

  - invoice ID
  - customer ID (Foreign key)
  - delivery date
  - invoice date
  - due date
  - payment status
- Store offers and invoices with

  - Several lines: text, amount, per item price
  - Calculate the total price per line
  - Calculate the total price per offer
  - Calculate the total VAT per offer in 2 rates (reduced rate and standard rate)
- Export single invoice / single offer to XML
- Export complete data into standard file format (XML / CSV) in case I need to replace the application later
- Keep the data local
- Provide basic security (password protection)

From the solutions I've seen so far, I have to say that I don't like the existing CRM tools because they offer too many features that I don't need. I really need it simple and stupid. I don't want

- PDF generation - I use Latex to generate the invoice PDFs. That's why I need the XML export
- Anything web-based - this is too much security risk and I have a bad Internet connection
- SQL-based solutions - keep it small and simple
- Multiuser operation - since I'm the only user
- Project management features - done in other application
- Employee management - I'm the only employee
- Calendars - I use Thunderbird + Lightning
- Sending emails - I use Thunderbird
- Payment management / connection to any bank account
- Forecasts
- Reporting
- Marketing features
- Document templates
- Workflow tracking
- Document management
- Service / Repair / Maintenance tracking
- Support ticket management
- Bug tracking
- Requirements Engineering features

I have tried:

- looking for a suitable CRM tool online, but all of them seem web-based or have 10+ features that I don't need.
- Excel, but it's hard to keep the data separated

Price: 50 € one time

License: commercial use obviously, no expiration

Answer (score 1):

Until someone writes better answer, I would say that we offer such a system with all these features (and without most features from your '*don't need this*' list) but I can't be delivered at given price. But maybe someone posts the answer...

My points are:

- reagrding "no SQL-based solution" – I don't think this is a good idea. You can still run free SQL server locally without even noticing it on system performance. Please note that your Access solution is SQL-based, too.
- if no one gives better answer, I would advice you simply to run your previous well established solution.

  - I think you can install even the old Office package. Hopefully there shouldn't be a conflict with new one if you do NOT install anything but Access.
  - Or you can consider purchasing new Access, too. It might still get cheaper on bottom line than any other available way (if you consider all needed time and effort).
  - Or you can rewrite your solution in some free software, for example in [Base application (of Libre Office suite)](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/). On bottom line this can still get more expensive than upgrading your Access, though.

Comment: I immediately agree on the SQL-based. I probably meant MS SQL Server based. I had enough problems configuring that thing, even in Express edition. Looking for an Access replacement sounds like a reasonnable approach which I didn't think of before you wrote it. I immediately found [MDB Viewer Plus](http://www.alexnolan.net/software/mdb_viewer_plus.htm) which seems to work and is even free. I'm not happy with OpenOffice / LibreOffice products I have to admit. I tried both, but that's why I bought MS Office again.

Comment: Regarding MS-SQL server: if you install it locally by clicking Next... Next... Next... Finish there are hardly any problems. (Unless you have corporate machine with restricting policies set by administrators etc.)

Answer (score -1):

What about Salesforce? https://corevalue.net/what-is-salesforce/
This CRM is a must for any business and helps to assist and identify your client,so that you’ll never have to worry about losing revenue as a result of incomplete data.

Comment: It seems there is no 50 € one time fee version. All versions I found are paid monthly. Also, I didn't find the possibility of doing a local installation. It seems all cloud based. The link you provided gives me a timeout. Could you please extend your answer in a way that explains how my requirements are met?

Comment: It may be better to link the actual Salesforce website rather than some sort of 3rd-party reseller/hosting provider: https://www.salesforce.com/